# Trouble with cross-compiling an c++ openCV application for the beaglebone black

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I hoping somebody has a quick solution because I'm getting a tiny, weeny bit frustrated.
I'm trying to cross-compile an openCV application for my Beaglebone Black (BBB) on my Linux Ubuntu 14.04 computer.
I installed the cross compilers: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 en arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8. cross . These work when I compile a simple c++ program without linking to 3th party libs, like openCV.

Because I want to compile for my BBB I mounted (samba) my beaglebone in the folder /mnt/BBB/ on my linux computer. And I tried the following code (which is a copy of http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", 1 );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

With the following command:

```
arm-g++ -I/mnt/BBB/usr/local/include -I/mnt/BBB/usr/local/include/opencv -L/mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib  -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching     -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab main.cpp -o main
```

But I receive the following error:

```
/tmp/ccX4FOL8.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xa6): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xe2): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
/tmp/ccX4FOL8.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2EPKc[_ZN2cv6StringC5EPKc]+0x2a): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccX4FOL8.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0xa): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccX4FOL8.o: In function `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11_InputArrayC2ERKNS_3MatE[_ZN2cv11_InputArrayC5ERKNS_3MatE]+0x34): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
/tmp/ccX4FOL8.o: In function `cv::_InputArray::~_InputArray()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv11_InputArrayD2Ev[_ZN2cv11_InputArrayD5Ev]+0x24): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
/tmp/ccX4FOL8.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccX4FOL8.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator=(cv::Mat const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_[_ZN2cv3MataSERKS0_]+0xb4): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
/tmp/ccX4FOL8.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x3e): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or what could be done better?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are not linking the library properly! Why aren't you using CMake?

```
 target_link_libraries(your_project ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Here you find the full reference on Cross compiling: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling

Anyway, I've found this on OpenCV forum group:

[Cross compile OpenCV but failed to find 3rd party library](http://answers.opencv.org/question/7138/cross-compile-opencv-but-failed-to-find-3rd-party-library/)

Comment: I'm linking it on the command line with the argument - L/mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib at least that is what I hope i'm doing ;-) I have never used cmake. Maybe it's about time for me to learn it. But first I want to test my setup

Comment: You are pointing probably to wrong libs. try to put the full path to the single libs instead

Comment: I tried arm-g++ -I/mnt/BBB/usr/local/include -I/mnt/BBB/usr/local/include/opencv -L/mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib -l/mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib/ope
ncv_core -l/mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib/opencv_highgui main.cpp -o main 
But to no avail:
the error is now:
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -l/mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib/opencv_core
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -l/mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib/opencv_highgui

Comment: Result is:
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -l/mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -l/mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

double checking the folder with
ll /mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib | grep opencv_core  show the file is present

Comment: mmm...try to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in this way: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/BBB/usr/local/lib and try to recompile with your original command

Comment: Still not completely solved but found a work around, using cmake. Most of my code can be executed on my linux computer x64 ubuntu and on my BBB arm. So testing is done on my computer and later on it is compiled on my BBB when I want to test BBB specific functions. Thank you blackibiza

Comment: @JelleSpijker actually, from generated CMake files in your build directory, you can even spot the Makefile, so you can read how gcc links all together the libraries, just for you to know it and debug further.
Anyway, CMake ist the best solution in these cases, because the more libraries you have, the more difficult is to use gcc from command line